# Pequeño inconveniente usando for dentro de una funcion

Tags: javascript

Hace poco empecé a programar y estoy queriendo llevar un ejercicio que me dieron en la facu, a una función en Js, pero no se porque no resulta:

La idea es que valorTotal en este caso se multiplique 3 veces por 2, pero cuando tiro console.log, solo se multiplica una vez y ya.. y realmente no entiendo que es lo que esta mal.. si me pueden dar una mano estaría mas que agradecido, desde ya mil gracias.

```
function operacion(canales, bits, decibeles) {
  var valores = 2 ** bits;
  var valorTotal = valores * canales;
  var a = decibeles / 6;
  

   for (var i = 0; i < a; i++) {
    var multi = valorTotal * 2;
   }
     document.write(multi);
      //var resultado = Math.log(multi) / Math.log(2);
   }
     operacion(16, 16, 18);
```

Comment: Declara `var multi = 0` antes del bucle, y dentro pon esto: `multi = multi + valorTotal * 2;`  a ver si es lo que quieres, que no lo tengo tan claro

Answer (score 1):

Estás declarando la variable multi en cada iteración de tu for.
Podés declararla una sola vez y así te saldría la multiplicación tres veces. Por ejemplo:

```
let multi = valorTotal;
for (let i = 0; i < a; i++) {
    multi = multi * 2;
}
```

Comment: Utilizar `var` dentro de un bloque `for` es poco menos que un suicidio. Te vas a encontrar con errores que no puedas explicarte y es por no declarar la variable con `let`. [Te invito](https://youtu.be/KbzZf3LWB-Q?t=309) a ver este ejemplo práctico. Gracias por tu colaboración de todas formas.

Comment: Esta sería la respuesta adecuada, pero utilizando `let` en lugar de `var`.

Comment: muy cierto a diferencia del var, el let te marca error cuando lo declaras más de una vez. Gracias por tu aporte @Liyo

Comment: @manuxo Muchas gracias! Estaba tan frustrado que no lo vi, ahora funciona bárbaro!

Answer (score 0):

buenas declara la variable antes del for y si quieres que en multi se guarde una vez por cada iteracion entonces dentro del for multi = valorTotal * 2; pero siempre sera el mismo resultado, si lo que quieres es que en multi se valla sumando el resultado de valorTotal*2  pon multi += (valorTotal * 2);